# Display: Inline-block not working for me

Tags: html, css

I'm starting out and practicing creating a website but I've had problems with making my images appear horizontally. I tried using display: inline-block, but the pictures remain vertical. Sorry if this is a simple mistake, but it has been bugging me for hours. Partial HTML:

```css
/*Main CSS*/

/*All Styling*/

* {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
/*All Text Styling*/

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}
/*Visited Page and Hover Link Color*/

a:visited,
a:hover {
  color: #838383;
}
/*Body Styling*/

body {}
/*Section and Footer Wrapper*/

#sfwrapper {
  max-width: 940px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: gray;
}
/*Ordered Lists*/

ol {
  list-style-type: none;
}
/*Head*/

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  color: #8c8c8c;
}
/*Subhead*/

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #8c8c8c;
}
/*NAV Styling*/

nav {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
/*Gallery Styling*/

#gallery {
  display: inline-block;
}
/*Footer Styling*/

footer {
  font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

```html
<ol id="gallery">
  <li>
    <a href="img/placeholder.png">
      <img src="img/placeholder.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <p>placeholder</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="img/placeholder.png">
      <img src="img/placeholder.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <p>placeholder</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="img/placeholder.png">
      <img src="img/placeholder.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <p>placeholder</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="img/placeholder.png">
      <img src="img/placeholder.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <p>placeholder</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Simply add `inline-block` to `li` and not to `ol`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pop the `display: inline-block;` on the `li` in the CSS.

```
#gallery li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is a live example: http://codepen.io/alexmccabe/pen/VjzzjZ, my added code is at the bottom of the CSS.

*As an aside, I would refrain from using IDs on elements unless you have a very good reason, it could create specificity issues in the future.*